# Maths within a ViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to execute some simple maths, depending on choices (buttons) pressed.
    I have 3 sets of buttons, and one will be pressed for each value required.
    I will then add these 3 values together to create a Total variable
    in the CalcViewController class I have created, to which the buttons are connected.
    a) I want to assign a value to each button pressed in CalcViewController.m 
    Can all this be done in CalcViewController.m, or is it done in AppDelegate.m ??
    I have not carried out Maths in Objective C ios before - my background is C++.
    Can anyone help??
    Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to ocjective-c world. Everything can be done inside your CalcViewController class. Just create three different variables to store all button's action specific data and carry on with your calculation.

Comment: You should NEVER do any logic in the AppDelegate except things relating specifically to state changes(app closing, re-open etc...), push notifications etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah add a property for the current value of the calculation:

```
@interface CalcViewController : UIViewController
@property (assign) NSInteger total;
@end
```

Then attach each button's action to the following action methods (in IB) and get them to do whatever is required to the total:

```
// Private methods
@implementation CalcViewController ()
- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button3Pressed:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation CalcViewController

...

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender
{
    self.total = self.total + 1;    // or _total += 1;
}

- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender
{
    self.total = self.total + 2;    // or _total += 2;
}

- (IBAction)button3Pressed:(id)sender
{
    self.total = self.total + 3;    // or _total += 3;
}

@end
```

(Obviously this is just *ballpark* given the loose requirements specification supplied).